# google sheets - Sum all above rows with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum

I want to do Pareto analysis, So I have column A which is ordered Z->A. I want to fill the column B as it is the sum of previous records in A. just like the example:

[image]

How Can I rewrite the B formula using ARRAYFORMULA function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;SUMIF(ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A); A2:A)))
```